# CakePHP4: Convert or cast Cake\ORM\Entity to actual entity for type hinting

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Let's say I have a method that is expecting an Invoice entity as a parameter. So I add the type hint `Invoice` like so:

```
public function doThatThing (Invoice $invoiceEntity)
{
    // ... operate on $invoiceEntity
}
```

Unfortunately, when I pass the results of `InvoiceTable->get(123)`, I get the error "TypeError: Argument 1 passed to doThatThing must be an instance of App\Model\Entity\Invoice, instance of Cake\ORM\Entity given..." in my unit tests.

Is there a good way to cast or convert the generic ORM results of `->get()` to the specific Entity type that I know it must be?

Comment: If you're getting an object of type `Cake\ORM\Entity` from that call, then `InvoiceTable` is almost certainly not *your* invoice table implementation, but rather a generic Cake Table object that happens to get to the right database table because of naming conventions. Look into where that table object is coming from, that'll be the source of your issue.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I experience the same issue. In this case, I would be getting table object from `FactoryLocator::get('Table')->get('Invoice');` and it returns as a generic `RepositoryInterface` and not `InvoiceTable`. Is there a preferred alternative to get table objects?

Comment: @tyriker, Is your table class called "InvoiceTable" or "InvoicesTable"?

Comment: In my case, it actually is `InvoiceTable` (singular) with a `$this->setTable('invoices');` inside it.

Comment: Could it be a namespace problem? [Configure Namespace](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/table-objects.html#configuring-the-namespace-to-locate-orm-classes) in conjunction with [Declare className](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.ORM.Locator.TableLocator.html#get())
"Define the specific class name to use. If undefined, CakePHP will generate the class name based on the alias. For example 'Users' would result in App\Model\Table\UsersTable being used. If this class does not exist, then the default Cake\ORM\Table class will be used."

Answer (score 0):

@greg-schmidt got me looking in the right direction. I'm afraid my question only mentioned the key clue in passing when I said "in my unit tests."

As it turns out, my unit test has a fake invoice table that extends `InvoiceTable`. My fake *does* call `setTable` and `setAlias` so that it looks like the real table.

But when I call `get()` on the fake, the call chain bypasses InvoiceTable, lands in ORM/Table, and eventually calls into ORM/Query. When ORM/Table calls the constructor on ORM/Query, it passes `$this`, which is an instance of my fake, and not of the real, underlying InvoiceTable (`setTable` and `setAlias` have no effect at this point). And as @greg-schmidt guessed,

> `InvoiceTable` is almost certainly not your invoice table implementation

My solution will be to have my fake invoice implement its own `get()` method which will return the response from a *real* InvoiceTable.